# Xubuntu 22.04: no DNS after PXE/overlay boot

Tags: 22.04, network-manager, dns, pxe

I am using dnsmasq on my server to boot our clients via PXE (both traditional BIOS and UEFI); the NFS-root is readonly and the clients use an overlay-root. This worked fine for Xubuntu 18.04 clients.

After upgrading to 22.04, the resulting client system has no DNS-resolution: I can ping an ip-address, but `ping google.com` gives the error "Temporary failure in name resolution".

I have reproduced the problem with a fresh 22.04 installation (minimum install using the provided iso from https://xubuntu.org/release/22-04/ plus overlayroot package).

I used following diagnostics:

```
$ resolvectl  Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp0s3) Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

$ nmcli d show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s3
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:00:27:52:C3:FC
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected (externally))
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     enp0s3
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.8.2/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.8.100
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.8.100, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.8.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::a00:27ff:fe52:c3fc/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ::1/128, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

I have found two workarounds:

1. start dhclient manually: $ sudo dhclient
2. change configuration in nm-connection-editor: When starting the editor, I have a recently-used configuration entry named "enp0s3". On the tab "IPv4 Settings": change Method from "Manual" to "Automatic (DHCP)"

After dhclient has run, resolvectl shows a valid DNS configuration:

```
$ resolvectl 
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp0s3)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.8.100
       DNS Servers: 192.168.8.100
        DNS Domain: my.domain
```

Both solutions seem not completely satisfactory to me...
Can somebody help with finding the root cause of the problem and fixing it in a stable way (maybe even upstream)?

Comment: I have checked the DHCP requests to the server (using a short lease time of 2m). After the PXE-boot + NFS mount has finished, the client system sends no DCHP requests to the server. This seems very wrong.
After configuring the Method to Auto (as described above), the client starts sending regular DHCP requests, as expected.
This seems to point to the root cause of the problem....